# Making java wait until a property is called for?

Tags: java, stack-overflow, jogl

I recently started working with JOGL, so I made a vector class. Inside this class, I used the line

```
    public Vector unit=new Vector(x/length,y/length,z/length);
```

To find the unit vector. And of course, this causes a stackoverflow. Is there any way to make java wait for unit to be called before running this or will I have to make unit a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woukld personally create a second constructor, which calculates the unit vector and sets its own unit vector to itself. You should ideally use private values and a get method as Ernest suggests. The reason for this is that otherwise other classes can simply overwrite the x,y,z, etc. values if they have access to one of your objects. Java has a tradition of using final classes for pure data storage. See the `String` class for example. You can't modify an existing `String`, only create a new `String`. Once created, a `String` remains the same. For your purposes it might not matter much, but in a different context it may cause your application to misbehave, if your class is used by someone who doesn't have a clue. It might even be a security risk in some cases.

You could simply ignore this and access the variables directly, and enjoy the less cluttered code and small performance increase. But I would still suggest knowing what the problem is for the future.

Anyway, below is my suggested code for solving the unit vector problem, minus getter methods.

```
import java.lang.Math;

class Vector{
    public double x,y,z,length;
    public Vector unit;

    public static void main(String[]s){
        new Vector(5,5,5);

    }

    public Vector(double x, double y, double z){
        this.length = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);

        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;

        this.unit = new Vector(x/length, y/length, z/length, true);
    }

    private Vector(double x, double y, double z, boolean isUnitVector){
        // Temp variable for calculating the length
        double length = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);

        if (isUnitVector){
            this.length = 1;

            this.x=x/length;
            this.y=y/length;
            this.z=z/length;

            this.unit = this;
        }else{
            this.length = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);

            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            this.z=z;

            this.unit = new Vector(x/length, y/length, z/length, true);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not entirely happy with the code duplication between the constructors that follows from the boolean argument. In practice, I would probably create a factory class, `VectorFactory` with one static method, whose only job is to create  Vector objects. Or maybe just use Java's own `javax.vecmath.Vector3d` and related classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easy enough, but you'll need to fix your design a bit. Most importantly, as is almost always the case with all member variables, `unit` should be *private*, and all access to it should be through a method named something like `getUnit()`. Then, you simply write `getUnit()` to check whether `unit` has been initialized or not:

```
public synchronized Vector getUnit() {
    if (unit == null)
        unit = new Vector(x/length,y/length,z/length);
    return unit;
}
```

I've made this method `synchronized` so that you'll avoid any problems if two different threads call `getUnit()` at around the same time, and `unit` hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The reason I had it public was because I enjoyed just doing `Vector.unit` or `Vector.x` instead of `Vector.getX()`. Is there any big reason why it should be private instead of public besides proper syntax etiquette?

Comment: You make it private to force clients to use the method rather than directly accessing the variable; you want them to use the method so you can delay initializing the variable. You can name it `unit()` if you want the name to be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a constructor which decides itself whether it is a unit vector or not. If it is a unit vector, then `unit` points to itself. This will break the recursion of the constructor.
The only problem might be numbers where `length` is not exactly `1.0` due to rounding errors.

```
public class Vector {
    public double x, y, z;
    public Vector unit;

    public Vector(double x, double y, double z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        double length = calcLength(x, y, z);
        if( length == 1.0 )  // perhaps add a little fuzz factor.
            this.unit = this;
        else
            this.unit = new Vector(x/length, y/length, z/length);
    }
}
```

Comment: The fuzz factor would most certainly be needed. The thing with your code is that length will converge to 1 as the loop is repeated. It may converge fast enough that the true clause of the if statement is taken after say 20 recursions. This means you may not get a hard error, but worse performance. I haven't done the experiment, but it's something to watch out for!

Comment: Now I did try it, and it actually doesn't appear to be a problem. I couldn't get it to recurse even one extra time, even using pretty extreme values. So this probably shouldn't be a problem. Even if it repeats once, the value should converge so quickly it doesn't matter performance wise.